# Why can't new int[] and new[] be omitted for arguments and elements of an array?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][] data =// new int[][] has been omitted here!
    {
        new int[] {1,2,3},// new int[] cannot be omitted
        new int[] {1,2,3,4}// new int[] cannot be omitted
    };

    Foo(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });// new[] cannot be omitted
}

static void Foo(int[] data) {/* implementation omitted */}
```

Why can't `new int[]` and `new[]` be omitted for arguments and elements of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array initializer syntax (`{ ... }`) can only be used to initialize a **field** or **variable**.

There is no default initialization for the elements of a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). Because it's elements are also arrays. That's why you have to use `new []` when you declare them.

That's why you can't do that;

```
int[][] data =
{
    {1,2,3},
    {1,2,3,4}
};
```

But you can do that in single of multi-dimensional array because theirs elements are variable.

```
int[,] data =
{
   {1,2,3},
   {1,2,3}
};
```

or

```
int[] data =
{
   1,
   2,
   3
};
```

From [`12.6 Array initializers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The context in which an array initializer is used determines the type
>   of the array being initialized. In an array creation expression, the
>   array type immediately precedes the initializer. In a field or
>   variable declaration, the array type is the type of the field or
>   variable being declared.

For parameter part, there is no `new` usage for any type of arrays. Read [`10.5.1 Method parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645761%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For most comman usage is [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx). For example;

```
static void Foo(params int[] data) {/* implementation omitted */}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
    Foo(array);
    Foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Actually, `Foo(1, 2, 3, 4);` automatically creates a four-element `int[]` with the given values. It equals to call `Foo(new int[] {1,2,3,4})`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
int[,] data2 =// new int[][] has been omitted here!
{
    {1,2,3},  // new int[] would make no sense
    {1,2,3}   
};
```

and that's partially your answer. The initializer you want to use already has another meaning.

Suppose you wrote `var data3 = { {1,2}, {2, 3} };`. Would `data3` be an `int[,]` or an `int[][]` ?

Comment: `{ {1,2},{2,3} }` might be a `Dictionary<int,int>` as well

Comment: @Gusdor - yeah, actually `var` doesn't work here for more or lees that reason. The argument still stands.

Comment: @Gusdor: But the compiler should be able to infer from the context. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A side-note, really: you can omit the types in the inner array declarations:

```
int[][] data =
{
    new [] {1,2,3},
    new [] {1,2,3,4}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Foo(int[] data) {/* implementation omitted */}
```

new

```
    static void Foo(params int[] data)
```

To provide the invoke of array of elements as method parameters , you need to use the key word params

Comment: That's not what OP asks

Comment: It does somewhat answer the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that feature is not implemented as specification doesn't say anything about that.

> The context in which an array initializer is used determines the type
>   of the array being initialized. In an array creation expression, the
>   array type immediately precedes the initializer. In a field or
>   variable declaration, the array type is the type of the field or
>   variable being declared. When an array initializer is used in a field
>   or variable declaration, such as:

```
int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
```

Taken from [12.6 Array initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)